# How to accomplish some tasks within cubic with the goal to create a custom Ubuntu image ready to Pass-Through an nvidia GPU

Tags: customization, live-cd, lxde, livedvd

I'm trying to understand how to customize Ubuntu 22.04 to satisfy my needs and also because I want to re-distribute a version of Ubuntu ready for the users who wants to passthru their nvidia gpu automatically inside a virtual machine without to configure everything from scratch. I admit that I have some troubles to find some good documentation to learn how to do it in a structured way.

I've already installed my customized copy of ubuntu 22.04 on a separate disk. Unfortunately inside /etc/skel I don't have /.config ; and on that system I've configured xfce4 to start automatically. It does not seem to be so easy. I would like to save time,so can you explain how to accomplish the points below ? maybe I will understand how and what to do next if someone can clarify a little bit of a something :

> 1. how to start automatically lxde as default dm for every user
>    created on the post installation of Ubuntu.
> 2. how to choose lxde instead of unity as default dm as soon as ubuntu
>    booted the first time
> 3. how to do add every user created to the libvirt group

I tried with this : **sudo usermod -a -G libvirt test**

but it's not good since I don't want to create the user test and it's not a good idea to start virt-manager as root.

That's all for now.

thanks.

Comment: LXDE is a desktop & not a WM or DM.  LXDE is WM & DM agnostic though the LXDE project did use `lxdm` at one point (Lubuntu used `lightdm` instead when they used LXDE but haven't for 8+ releases now)... Unity hasn't been a default since Ubuntu 17.04, but you mention 22.04 (where it's **not** the default)..

Comment: you have skipped all the questions that I have asked.

Comment: What questions?  LXDE is a desktop which is a different thing to a Display Manager.... thus "*how to start automatically lxde as default dm*" makes no sense at all...    likewise the other numbered points/questions...   (Unity 7 was a replacement to GNOME-Shell used by Ubuntu releases from 11.04 thru 17.04... it's not been default since 17.10 - but is still not a DM so isn't a default anything for 22.04)

Comment: 1) how to start automatically lxde as default dm for every user created on the post installation of Ubuntu when I want to use cubic to create a customized dvd; 2) how to choose lxde instead of unity (or whatever dm ubuntu 2204 uses on the live dvd) as default dm as soon as ubuntu booted the first time 3) how to do add every user created to the libvirt group when I want to use cubic for creating a customized dvd. All these questions are related to cubic.

Comment: LXDE is a desktop; thus cannot be started as a DM; DM & DEs are different things.. Unity likewise is a Shell (replacement for GNOME Shell) & thus not a DM & can't be started as a DM...   When Unity was used the DM was `lighdm`, but with modern releases `gdm3` is used..  When Lubuntu used LXDE it used `lightdm` too (now it's one of three *flavors* using `sddm`), but LXDE's default DM is `lxdm`  ... you're question(s) make no sense as mix different things..  LXDE is WM & DM agnostic..

Comment: It can be done. Infact Lubuntu uses lxde instead of unity or whatever it is called as default desktop on the ubuntu 22.04 live CD and it uses lxde even when lubuntu has been installed on a disk. So,on the internal file structure they made some changes ; they removed Unity and they added lxde. This is what I want to do when I customize my ISO with cubic. I could use lubuntu directly,but in this way I will not learn how to use lxde instead of unity as default while I customize ubuntu 22.04 with cubic.

Comment: ok sorry. it's not unity,but GNOME 42.0.

Comment: [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) uses LXQt & supports only LXQt, not LXDE; our current manifest can be found [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/kinetic-desktop-amd64.manifest)  ... or you could look at our [*seed*](https://git.launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/ubuntu-seeds/+git/lubuntu/) files as to what we include; exclude...  Lubuntu also doesn't use `ubiquity`, having used `calamares` since 18.10 (Ubuntu Studio also share `calamares` with us)

Comment: 1) how to start automatically lxqt as default for every user created on the post installation of Ubuntu 22.04 2) how to choose lxqt instead of gnome 42 as default as soon as ubuntu 22.04 booted the first time 3) how to do add every user created on the post installation of ubuntu 22.04 to the libvirt group. I see that I should be root to do that. When I create a customized iso with cubic I read that I should place my shell script in /opt and the desktop files on /etc/skel/autostart. Tried but didn't work. When I launched virt-manager it refused to start because the live user is not root.